# error C3861: 'getGaborKernel': identifier not found

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to build the following code, but It failed because of the following error

```
error C3861: 'getGaborKernel': identifier not found
```

I have included the required header files and lib files. What could be the problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <math.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat in = imread("1.jpg",0);          // load grayscale
    Mat dest;
    Mat src_f;
    in.convertTo(src_f,CV_32F);
    extern ostream cerr;

    int kernel_size = 31;
    double sig = 1, th = 0, lm = 1.0, gm = 0.02, ps = 0;
    cv::Mat kernel = 
    getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size),sig, th, lm, gm, 
     ps);
    cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);

    cerr << dest(Rect(30,30,10,10)) << endl; // peek into the data

    Mat viz;
    dest.convertTo(viz,CV_8U,1.0/255.0);     
    imshow("k",kernel);
    imshow("d",viz);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: which opencv version are you using ?

Comment: @berak I tested the code with opencv 2.2 & opencv 2.3, also the same error.

Comment: both versions are outdated (and don't have it), and should no more be used. please get recent 2.4.11

Answer (score 0):

When C++ misses a prototype it issues an error. Your source obviously didn't include the header file with the appropriate prototype or the prototype is hidden by `#ifdef`s.

- Lookup the Header file that you expect that it contains the prototy of `getGaborKernel`.
- Check the option `Show includes` to see what header files are actually included. Verify the header found in the first step is in the list.
- Check the option `Preprocess to a file` to see what the preprocessor outputs after processing all `#ifdef`s in the generated `.i` file. Check why the prototype isn't in the output.
- Uncheck both options after you have found the problem. That's important for the `Preprocess to a file` option to get a `.obj` file instead of the `.i`.

Comment: harper , lacking any domain knowledge about opencv. it's a version problem(needs opencv 2.4.something), not a general c++ one (and your answer is far too generic)